# What's this string syntax means in javascripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, export

I currently try to learn node js myself, and I'm totally new to javascript too. When I try to read and understand the mongoose, I found this code, with no explanation.

In `router.js` :

```
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
exports.get = function(req, res) {
 req.requrl = url.parse(req.url, true);
 var path = req.requrl.pathname;
 if (/\.(css)$/.test(path)){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'});
  fs.readFile(__dirname + path, 'utf8', function (err, data){
   if (err) throw err;
   res.write(data, 'utf8');
   res.end();
  });
 } else {
  if (path === '/' || path === '/home') {
   require('./controllers/home-mongoose').get(req, res);
  } else {
   require('./controllers/404').get(req, res);
  }
 }
}
```

First of all, what is this `exports.get` ? I kind of understand that `exports = function functionA(){}` means that when I can do something like this :

```
var router = require('path/router.js');
router.functionA();
```

But I don't get what it means when you do `exports.get`.

Second, `/\.(css)$/.test(path)`. I don't get this expression syntax, anyone can explain it to me ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, what is this `exports.get` ? I kind of understand that `exports = function functionA(){}` means that when I can do something like this :
>
> ```
> var router = require('path/router.js');
> router.functionA();
> ```

`exports = function functionA(){}` actually doesn't do what you're thinking.

In Node, [`exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_exports) is simply a variable that initially refers to an `Object`. And, the line is setting a `get` property/method on that object.

```
console.log(exports); // {}

exports.get = function () {};

console.log(exports); // { get: function () {} }
```

The object that `exports` refers to is typically the same object that `require()` returns when referring to the module/file.

```
// `router` = `module.exports` from `./path/router.js`
var router = require('./path/router');
router.get()
```

For more information on `exports`, read through the [Modules documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) for Node.js

---

> Second, `/\.(css)$/.test(path)`. I don't get this expression syntax, anyone can explain it to me ?

The first portion of the expression, `/\.(css)$/`, is a [RegExp literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

The `/`s are the starting and ending delimiters, behaving similarly to the quotes around a string literal. And, between them, `\.(css)$` is the pattern being defined.

```
\.      // match a single period character
        // escaped to disable the period's "any character" meaning
(css)   // match the 3 characters, "css", within a capture group
$       // anchor the pattern to the end of the line/string
```

The expression could also be written with the `RegExp` constructor as:

```
new RegExp("\\.(css)$").test(path) // note the extra escape needed for the string
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
exports = function functionA(){}
```

You must set `module.exports`, not `exports`.  Also, you would use that with:

```
var router = require('path/router.js');
router();
```

Because you set the entire export, not a property called `functionA`.

However, you can set just properties on `exports`:

```
exports.get = function functionA(){}
```

This works this way because there is an `var exports = module.exports = {}` during the setup for a module, and `module.exports` is what's exported at the end.

Setting properties like that means that when you require the module, you can use that property:

```
var router = require('path/router.js');
router.get();
```

Your second question points to a line that uses a regular expression.  I suggest doing some research on them or asking a second question if you want to understand that particular one, but in Javascript you can write literal regular expressions by surrounding them with slashes (`/`) just like literal strings are surrounded by quotes (`"`/`'`).

Comment: Thanks. I get the first one. I will do research on the reg

Answer (score 0):

`/\.(css)$/`  is a regular expression, this one what it does is check if the given path/file extension is ".css".

There are two ways in javascript to construct a Regular expression:

1. Using a regex literal: `var reg = /[a-b]/;`
2. Or using the constructor function `var reg = new RegExp("[a-b]");`

You can read more about regexp [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

And about the first question, since @Aaron Dufour already explained it, I'll credit him ;)

Comment: Thanks. I will read that. Though I don't have enough power to upvote your awnser

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

1) The `exports` object is just an object that you use to make code in one file available to code elsewhere. So in your case, `exports.get` is simply defining a property called "get" and this property happens to be a function. For a good overview of Node.js module format, [see here](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/).

2) `/\.(css)$/.test(path)` is the equivalent of saying "hey, look at the variable "path" and see if it ends with ".css". For more info on `.test` [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: I see. I didn't get the `test` though. Normally it should be other way in other language like `path.test(...)`. Anyway, thanks alot